# I can't solve this problem can someone help me? "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The problem is how can i use send_keys? Because it is not writing in the search bar.

I search in the documents but i can't solve it.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 

# Open Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/xampp/htdocs/pegasus/chromedriver') 

# Going to website
driver.get("https://www.flypgs.com/en")

# Select button by class name and click on it.
frombtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-selection').click()
searchbtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-search__field").click()

# ERROR is here below on send_keys.
searchbtn.send_keys('Amsterdam')

time.sleep(1000000)
```

The error what is giving is:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
File "C:\xampp\htdocs\pegasus\app.py", line 17, in <module>
searchbtn.send_keys('Amsterdam')
```

Comment: it means your `searchbtn = driver...` doesnt have an attribute called `send_keys`. You are specifying an attribute when you `.` when calling a varible

Comment: your `searchbtn` has result from `click()` which returns `None`. You should assign to `searchbtn` value from `find_element_by_...` and later do `searchbtn.click()` and `searchbtn.send_key()`

Comment: `searchbtn is `None`; it doesn't have any attributes of interest to you.

Comment: What kind/class of object has a `send_keys` method?  The error means that `searchbtn` is not that kind.

Answer (score 1):

You assign wrong value to `searchbtn`

You assing value returned by `click()` which is always `None`

You have to do it in two steps

```
searchbtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-search__field")
searchbtn.click()
```

and then `searchbtn` is correct and you can use `send_key()`

---

After this change code works

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/xampp/htdocs/pegasus/chromedriver') 

driver.get("https://www.flypgs.com/en")

frombtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-selection')
frombtn.click()

searchbtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-search__field")
searchbtn.click()

searchbtn.send_keys('Amsterdam')

time.sleep(1000000)
```